# ios: libswiftCore.dylib crash swift

Tags: ios, swift, crash, app-store, testflight

I submitted app to beta review on app store and am getting crash on libswiftCore.dylib during application didFinishLoadWithRequest. When I compile and run code through Xcode everything works fine. When I upload on Testflight and user directly open using open button of Testflight it crashes. However it does not crash when open through app drawer by clicking on app icon after installing from testflight. Only crashes when opened directly from testflight and also during app store submission. The crash log is attached [here](http://pastebin.com/4bF4jd3X)

Comment: Do you mean application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, rather than didFinishLoadWithRequest? Also, I'm not completely sure what the "app drawer" is. Do you mean the home screen (or Springboard, which nobody says)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app will have different launch options in the options dictionary depending on how the app was launched. Since the app is only crashing in some situations, I suspect you are trying to access a launch option key that isn't present when the app is launched from another app. I can't pinpoint your exact problem without seeing your code, but here is an example of a possible cause of your problem:

```
if let options = launchOptions {
    let shortcut: UIApplicationShortcutItem = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey]!
}
```

If your app is launched from another app, it won't have this key, so implicitly unwrapping it will cause a crash. Or you might not be handling the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey` correctly. Check these, and you'll probably find the problem.

Comment: Thanks @ConfusedByCode I had already a launch option for remote notification which caused the crash.